# Custom UIView won't load in the main view when binded to @IBOutlet

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a custom view. But it seems like it won't load  when I bind a `@IBOutlet` to it, and therefore starts as NIL (*null*).

My following custom view looks like this (simplified)

```
import UIKit

class CounterView: UIView {
    private let progressLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private var progressLabel: UILabel = UILabel()

 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    override  func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupView()

    }

    private func setupView() {
        // setup the view
    }

    // some update and create methods on the progressLayer and progressLabel

}
```

As you can see, I am loading it on init and I have tried print methods inside them to see if it actually loads, and it does.

My ViewController looks like this, which uses a single Storyboard.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var counterView: CounterView!
}
```

I have also binded it to the custom class, in the storyboard. 
[image]

So every time I try to call counterView and/or its methods I am getting this error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

Comment: did u connec the outlet properly in storyboard ?

Comment: I feel stupid, that was indeed what I forgot. It has been driving me crazy the last couple of hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So every time I try to call counterView and/or its methods I am getting this error

But the problem lies in how you do that.

If you say `ViewController()`, for example, you create a "detached" ViewController with no knowledge of your storyboard design, so its `counterView` is certainly `nil`.

Similarly, in `prepareForSegue`, if the destination view controller were a ViewController, its outlets would not yet be connected and its `counterView` would be `nil`.